# AzureStorage CloudFileDirectory.ListFilesAndDirectories worthless?

Tags: azure-storage-files

So far I get a handle on my `CloudFileDirectory` and calling this method gives me a list of  `IListFileItem` objects, 1 for each file and directory in the given `CloudFileDirectory`, but I'm having trouble distinguishing which are *files* and which are *directories*.

Properties available on the `IListFileItem` include `Uri`, which is a `System.Uri` object, which has an `isFile` member, but this shows as *false* for my files **and** my directories.

I need to get lists of directories which I can drill into, lists of files I can work with, but so far I can't find a way to filter this mixed up list.

I can't think of a worthwhile use for a mixed list. I wonder why M$ didn't expose `ListFiles` and `ListDirectories` as separate methods. Maybe they had trouble distinguishing them and gave up.

Answer (score 11):

I found the answer here... [RobinDotNet's blog](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2014/07/12/using-the-azure-files-preview-with-the-storage-client-library/) **Using the Azure Files preview with the Storage Client Library**

Casting the received `IListFileItem` as `CloudFile` only works for files, otherwise resulting in `null`, and casting it as `CloudFileDirectory` only works for directories.

I ended up using Linq...

```
var azureDirectories = myShare.GetRootDirectoryReference()
    .GetDirectoryReference(myPath)
    .ListFilesAndDirectories()
    .OfType<CloudFileDirectory>();

var azureFiles = myShare.GetRootDirectoryReference()
    .GetDirectoryReference(myPath)
    .ListFilesAndDirectories()
    .OfType<CloudFile>();
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent listing the directory twice you could also do:

```cs
CloudFileDirectory rootDir = myShare.GetRootDirectoryReference();
// Get directory items once
IEnumerable<IListFileItem> azureItems = rootDir.ListFilesAndDirectories();
CloudFileDirectory azureDirectories = azureItems.OfType<CloudFileDirectory>();
CloudFile azureFiles = azureItems.OfType<CloudFile>();
```

Comment: Isn't this still enumerating twice since `GetEnumerator()` is called with each `OfType`?

Comment: It was more to prevent 2 online calls if there is no cache mechanism in place. Preventing doing this twice: `myShare.GetRootDirectoryReference().GetDirectoryReference(myPath).ListFilesAndDirectories()`